# Version Comparator 3 decimal places

Tags: java, android, comparison

Hello I am trying to compare version numbers of phone devices. My program is was crashing if a version comes in as 4.3.2 so I implemented Decimal format but now it just rounds my number from 4.3.2 to 4.3, but the program will be completely fine with a version number of something like 4.2 for example. How can I fix my comparator to be able to take in 3 decimals and not crash while still working for 2 decimals as well.

```
        @Override
        public int compare(InventoryCardViewModel lhs, InventoryCardViewModel rhs) {

            Phone lhp = phoneDataSource.getPhoneByDeviceID(lhs.getPhoneDeviceID.getValue());
            Phone rhp = phoneDataSource.getPhoneByDeviceID(rhs.getPhoneDeviceID.getValue());

            if(!lhp.versionNumber.equals(rhp.versionNumber)) {
                DecimalFormat df =  new DecimalFormat("#.#.#", new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("en_US")));
                try {
                    lhp.versionNumber = String.valueOf(df.parse(lhp.versionNumber).doubleValue());
                    rhp.versionNumber = String.valueOf(df.parse(lhp.versionNumber).doubleValue());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (Double.valueOf(lhp.versionNumber) > Double.valueOf(rhp.versionNumber)) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
```

Comment: Don't use a `DecimalFormat`; I would probably split on ``\\.`` and compare the resulting tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can't use a `DecimalFormat` here because the Java decimal types don't support arbitrary number of decimals (nor are the primitive types capable of arbitrary precision). Instead, I would split on a `\\.` and then use iteration to test the resulting tokens. Something like,

```
public class VersionComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String left, String right) {
        /* Handle nulls. */
        if (left == null) {
            if (right == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        } else if (right == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        /* Generate tokens */
        String[] lTokens = left.split("\\.");
        String[] rTokens = right.split("\\.");

        int len = Math.max(lTokens.length, rTokens.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            /* Check if both sides still have tokens */
            if (i < lTokens.length && i < rTokens.length) {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(lTokens[i]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(rTokens[i]);

                if (a < b) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (a > b) {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else if (i < rTokens.length) {
                /* No more tokens on the left hand side */
                return -1;
            } else {
                /* No more tokens on the right hand side */
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int compareVersions(String v1, String v2) {
    final String[] split1 = v1.split( "[.]" );
    final String[] split2 = v2.split( "[.]" );

    for ( int i = 0; i < split1.length; i++ ) {
        if ( i < split2.length ) {
            final int compare = Integer.valueOf( split1[ i ] )
                                       .compareTo( Integer.valueOf( split2[ i ] ) );

            if ( compare != 0 ) {
                return compare;
            }
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return split1.length == split2.length ? 0 : -1;
}
```